# Can one aggregate root contain nested childrens?

Tags: c#, asp.net, domain-driven-design

Two months ago I bought the book “Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns” by Scott Millet because I wanted to learn how to build a layered web application using design patterns. I used the case study from this book in my own application so everything is set up.

The problem I have is that I am not sure about my aggregate roots.

I have a user that can create collections. A user can add categories to a collection and keywords to the categories. It looks like this in my database:

```
- Users
    - PK: UserId

- Collections
    - PK: CollectionId
    - FK: UserId

- Categories
    - PK: CategoryId
    - FK: CollectionId

- Keywords
    - PK: KeywordId
    - FK: CategoryId
```

I don’t find it logical to make user the aggregate root of collection, but categories and keywords together form a collection. So I made user an aggregate root which has no children yet, and collections an aggregate root. A single collection can have multiple categories and categories can have multiple keywords. So when I want to add a category I do this:

```
public void CreateCategory(CreateCategoryRequest request)
    {
        Collection collection = _collectionRepository.FindCollection(request.IdentityToken, request.CollectionName);

        Category category = new Category { Collection = collection, CategoryName = request.CategoryName };

        ThrowExceptionIfCategoryIsInvalid(category);

        collection.AddCategory(category);

        _collectionRepository.Add(collection);
        _uow.Commit();
    }
```

Which works perfectly fine, but when I want to add a keyword I first need to get the collection and then get the category where I can add a keyword to and then commit the collection:

```
public void CreateKeyword(CreateKeywordRequest request)
    {
        Collection collection = _collectionRepository.FindCollection(request.IdentityToken, request.CollectionName);

        Category category = collection.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryName == request.CategoryName).FirstOrDefault();

        Keyword keyword = new Keyword { Category = category, KeywordName = request.KeywordName, Description = request.KeywordDescription };

        category.AddKeyword(keyword);

        _collectionRepository.Add(collection);
        _uow.Commit();
    }
```

And this just don’t feel right (is it?) what made me believe that I should maybe make category the aggregate root of keyword. But that raises another question: is it still valid that I have a collection aggregate which creates a category aggregate like I did in my first code example? Example: collection.Add(category);

Comment: A simple rule of thumb in this case would be to consider "does it make sense to have a category outside of a collection?" If not, making category a separate root doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: I thought about that to because I show collections at one page and categories with their keywords at another. But even though it is not an aggregate root, it still makes sense to add a keyword via the category object right?

Comment: Consider this then; does it make sense that the category has an identity outside the collection? Ie, if two users add a category with the same name, are they local to the collection or shared between the users?

Comment: They are local to the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An aggregate root can certainly contain nested children, however if those children are also aggregates that may be a warning that perhaps the aggregate is doing too much. In your case, I think `Collection` is an aggregate and `Category` is not, it is just an entity or even a value object belonging to the `Collection` aggregate and it happens to contain `Keyword` instances which are also value objects.

I would change the implementation so that the `CreateCategory` service method looks more like this:

```
public void CreateCategory(CreateCategoryRequest request)
{
        var collection = _collectionRepository.Get(request.IdentityToken, request.CollectionName);

        collection.AddCategory(request.CategoryName);

        _uow.Commit();
}
```

The `AddCategory` method on the `Collection` is responsible for creating the `Category` instance as well as error checking. This makes sense because it is the aggregate root and it is responsible for managing the cluster of entities and value objects it contains. There is no call to the Add method on the repository because the ambient unit of work should commit the changes.

The `CreateKeyword` method I would change to look more like:

```
public void CreateKeyword(CreateKeywordRequest request)
{
        var collection = _collectionRepository.Get(request.IdentityToken, request.CollectionName);

        collection.AddKeyword(request.CategoryName, request.KeywordName, request.KeywordDescription);

        _uow.Commit();
}
```

The `AddKeyword` method on `Collection` retrieves the appropriate `Category` and then adds a keyword to it, throwing exceptions if needed to enforce consistency and validity.

As you can see, there is a pattern to these two methods - first an aggregate is retrieved by a key, then a method on the aggregate is invoked, and finally everything is committed. In this way, the aggregates have more control over their own state and you avoid having an [anemic domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) as well as reducing the amount of code present in services.

For an in depth treatment of aggregate design, take a look at [Effective Aggregate Design by Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011).

Comment: Thankyou for your clear explanation. I did what you described and it works perfectly.

Comment: This is one approach but it has drawbacks - like having a bloated, God-object aggregate root because of all the AddSomething() methods of all entities that you have to cram into it. Instead, you could realize that your CreateKeywordRequest already contains the Category so you have all you need to do Category.AddKeyword() without resorting to Collection - just saying.

Comment: But my category object has a reference to a collection to indicate the foreign key in NHbibernate and I do not have that in my CreateKeywordRequest. So I would still need the collection when I want to add a keyword via the category right? I only have the strings to get a collection and a category.

Comment: @guillaume31- I believe all those methods are a good thing because they achieve encapsulation. However, it can be the case that the aggregate is doing a little too much. Then, it is possible to make Category an aggregate itself. The reason to make Category an aggregate can also be purely technical in that perhaps collection has the potential to contain too many categories to manage in a single consistency boundary.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't feel right because to add a new Keyword you start all the way from a Collection reference, while you could perfectly start from a Category reference instead. When the user adds a keyword, he certainly does so in the context of a Category so you probably have the Category in memory at that time.

Also, I don't get the `_collectionRepository.Add(collection)` at the end of each of your `Add[SomeSubEntity]()` methods. The Collection is already supposed to exist in the repository, so all you should do is save it, right ?

As for the nested aggregates, I find it a bit complicated and don't really see the benefit compared to 2 separate aggregates (Category and Collection).

Comment: You are right about the _collectionRepository.Add(collection). It doesn't make sense. I am still a beginner programmer so I probably read over something. A user first adds a category. After he created one, he or she can choose to add a keyword to it, or not. So I can make a method inside the collection repository that returns a category and to that category I can add a keyword. Right?

Comment: As I see it, you don't need a method that returns a category. Just keep the newly created Category instance and add a Keyword to it. Then commit your unit of work to save everything to the database.